# How to redirect to CodeIgniter controller using angular js

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter controller functions.
(example)

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Me extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
       {
            parent::__construct();
            if (is_logged_in()){if (is_admin()) { redirect('login');  }}
            else { redirect('login');}  
       }
    public function change_password()
    {
        $id=$this->session->userdata['user_data']['id'];
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

        $my_data=array(
            'pass'=>$data->pass,
            'new_pass'=>$data->new_pass,
            );
        $result=$this->vanesh_model->change_pass($id,$my_data);
        if($result==1)
        {
            $arr = array('msg' => "Password changed successfuly.", 'error' => '');
            $jsn = json_encode($arr);
            print_r($jsn);
        }
        else if($result==2)
        {
            $arr = array('msg' => "", 'error' => 'Old Password is Invalid');
            $jsn = json_encode($arr);
            print_r($jsn);
        }
        else if($result==3)
        {
            $arr = array('msg' => "", 'error' => 'Sorry, Password change failed');
            $jsn = json_encode($arr);
            print_r($jsn);
        }
    } 
}
?>
```

I am afraid of using angular session services, so I want to maintain sessions with only CI. What I am doing in my application is add, update, delete only if he is logged in. And I am using information stored in session. Consider the situation, suppose, I am logged in and doing something, side by side: I destroy the session using browser tools. Now I am continuing with application (doing operations like: change password). I have/had maintained error messages, success messages, its ok. If session OFF, it gives error message. But instead of error messages, I want to redirect to LOGIN page(with page refresh).
**Note:** For CI Login controller, I didn't used angular js. I have used angularjs only after login.

- If by opening new tab I destroy the session, and come back to application's tab: I am able to perform tasks(may be with errors,). If session is OFF I see this in Browser's console: `http://localhost/ums/login`
  This is because of CI constructor(please look over the code).

Answer (score 0):

You should separate angular and CI as much as possible, since both have view-controller it creates a mess. Instead you should have CI in a separate folder, call it api, for example, after that anything you will need from CI should be acessed from angular with ajax calls.

I made a small webapp a while ago and this seemed to be the best way to organize code.
Few updates have been made to angular since then so if there's a better way please let me know

Answer (score 0):

**Solved.**
Used javascript function. **Checking session by http request everytime**. If response comes "1". Means redirect to login as:

```
/* function for checking logged-in and role */
function check_session()
{
    $.get("servercontroller/check_session", function(data, status){
         if(data=="1") /* error 1 => un-athorized user */
        {
            window.location.href="/login-page-url";
        }
        });
}
```